# Should I overwinter my Crocosmia bulbs indoors, or plant them?

Tags: flowers, planting, bulbs

I just dug out some bulbs of what I believe is [*Crocosmia x crocosmiiflora* 'Honey Angels'](https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/215275/Montbretia-Honey-Angels/Details). I'm wondering now what to do with them.

Should I store them until spring? In that case, which conditions should I keep them in?

Or should I put them in the ground now (autumn)? If so, how deep should I plant them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paris is in USDA hardiness [zone 8](http://www.uk.gardenweb.com/forums/zones/hze3.html), and *Crocosmia x crocosmiiflora* 'Honey Angels' is hardy [in zones 5-9](http://www.99roots.com/en/plants/montbretia-honey-angels-p36964/pdf), so there is no reason for you to store them until spring. Plant them in well-worked topsoil, about 3-5 inches deep (lower in lighter soil, higher where there is heavy clay), and about 6" apart.